# How to send the object via intent to another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I am developing in Android. I tried sending a Bluetooth object to another Activity.

**Code**:

```
    BluetoothSocket btSocket;

Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_BT_SOCKET,btSocket);
startActivity(i);
```

But it seems to be not working and it shows an error like:

> Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String,
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket)

How to send the Bluetooth object via intent to another Activity in Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: @Kiya it show Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket).

Comment: As far as I know, you can only pass objects which can implement Parcelable or Serializable interface, I also was stuck as you are so what I did was made the object static and accessed it from other class like: public static BluetoothSocket btSocket; and when I went to other activity I just did BluetoothSocket copyOfBtSocket = ActivityA.btSocket;

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a `BluetoothSocket` instance in a `Bundle` or pass it as an `Intent` "extra" like that. This would require serializing and deserializing the object, which would make a copy of the object. You can't copy a socket like that. What you want to do is just share the object between multiple activities. The easiest way to do that is to put a reference to the object in a `public static` variable somewhere and just use it from all activities that need access.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to send and retrieve objects:

//To pass:
    intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

```
// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Comment: If you are trying this make sure you cast it @
i.putExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS,(Serializable) address);

Comment: I have try , it will show 'putExtra(java.lang.String, android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket) at i.putExtra("MyClass", (Serializable)btSocket);

Comment: use getparceable() while retrieving.

Comment: OP want to pass a `BluetoothSocket` object. Since this class does not implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`, it cannot be passed this way. This object is a connection to a Bluetooth device, so it makes no sense to serialize and deserialize it. That would make a copy of the object and you can't copy a socket like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper class

```
public class BluetoothSocketHelper implements Serializable {

    public BluetoothSocket btSocket;

    //Constructor + getter/setters
}
```

Sending from ActivityA:

```
BluetoothSocketHelper bluetoothSocketHelper;

Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_BT_SOCKET, bluetoothSocketHelper);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in ActivityB:

```
private BluetoothSocket btSocket;

if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
    bluetoothSocketHelper = (BluetoothSocketHelper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_BT_SOCKET);
    btSocket = (BluetoothSocket) bluetoothSocketHelper.getBluetoothSocket();
}
```

Comment: You cannot make a `BluetoothSocket` serializable just by declaring that it `implements Serializable`. This is a socket, which is a connection to a Bluetooth device. When you serialize and deserialize something, it makes a copy of the object. You can't copy a socket like this. You can't put a socket object in a `Bundle` or as an `Intent` "extra" this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Wun I know it is too late but I found a simple way to do that, in your first activity just start the activity and send your object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("rideId", yourObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the Second Activity:

```
String id = extras.getString("rideId");
try {
   JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(id);
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pass it as a bundle through the intent

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putParcelable("yourObject key name", YOUR_OBJECT); //make YOUR_OBJECT implement parcelable
 Intent intents = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
 intents.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_DATA, bundle);
 startActivity(intents);
```

At recieving end (ActivityB.class)

```
if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_DATA)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_DATA);
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(yourObject key name)) {
            Object yourObject = bundle.getParcelable(yourObject keyname);
    }
```

Comment: OP is trying to pass a `BluetoothSocket` . This class does not implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable` so it cannot be put in a `Bundle`.